# How to set optional json in nest struct

Tags: json, go

I tried to set an optional json config in nest struct, when i need this json it will appear, otherwise it will not exist.

```
type Test struct {
  Data NestTest `json:"data"`
}

type NestTest struct {
  NestData1 string `json:"data1"`
  NestData2 string `json:"data2,omitempty"`
}

test := Test{
  Data: NestTest{
    NestData1: "something",
  },
}

b, err := json.Marshal(test)
fmt.Sprintf("the test struct json string is: %s", string(b))

output:
{"data":{"data1":"something","data2":""}}

expect:
{"data":{"data1":"something"}}
```

Comment: are you sure? https://play.golang.org/p/vF-12K5Qml3

Comment: also I think you mean `type Test Struct {` - not `var Test Struct {`

Comment: even with your update - I see no issue: https://play.golang.org/p/vU29dTvL_Qg

Answer (score 1):

All fields are optional when unmarshalling (you won't get an error if a struct field doesn't have an associated value in the JSON). When marshaling, you can use `omitempty` to not output a field if it contains its type's zero value:

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal

```
var Test struct {
  Data string `json:"data,omitempty" validate:"option"`
}
```

Comment: When i set this config, It also has a default value. i update my question.

Comment: Double-check because your code gives your expected output, not your reported output: https://play.golang.org/p/0aNzJJ0D0xE

Comment: Shared my specific example: https://play.golang.org/p/9MlTE_OFkcJ

Comment: @ccd Try https://play.golang.org/p/9NEmgNAiOY0.  `omitempty` won't omit empty zero values for nested structs.  You need to use a pointer to the struct you want as optional.

Comment: Is it the pointer for struct will add the pressure about ram?

Comment: @ccd no. The struct always takes the same amount of memory, the pointer adds 4 or 8 bytes.